# Is this Function Differentiable? $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2-4x+5, & \text{if } x\neq 0\\ 3x+5, & \text{if } x=0 \end{cases}$

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2-4x+5,  & \text{if $x\neq0$ } \\ 3x+5, & \text{if $x=0$ } \end{cases}$$
Can we Present this function as a Differentiable Function whose Derivate Function is Not Continues?
I Suppose the Derivate Function would be:
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x-4,  & \text{if $x\neq0$ } \\ 3, & \text{if $x=0$ } \end{cases}$$
Am I Right?
And is this function basically differentiable?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, you are not right. Also are you sure you wrote down the function correctly?

Comment: The definition you give for $f$ is equivalent to just saying $f(x)=x^2-4x+5$.

Comment: @Davis C. Ullrich I know it seems Strange but the function gives us a different Equation when $x=0$ so the derivate would be different too? Why isn't it? I'm kind of Confused.

Comment: So if  I say $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x+x$ you think $f$ and $g$ should have different derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

You are not right. Since $3x+5=5$ for $x=0$ we have

$f(x)=x^2-4x+5$ for all $x$

Then $f$ is differentiable on $ \mathbb R$ with $f'(x)=2x-4$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do what you're suggesting. The main problem is that a derivative is defined based on the values of a function in a *neighborhood* of a point, i.e., in some open region around the point, not *just* what it's at the one point. Consider the basic definition of what $f'(0)$, if it exists, actually states, i.e.,

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

In your case, you have that $f(x) = 3x + 5$ *only* at $x = 0$, so the $f(x) = x^2 - 4x  + 5$ definition would actually be used *instead* for the $x \to 0$ points being checked in the limit.

As [David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248223/david-c-ullrich)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551258/is-this-function-differentiable-fx-begincases-x2-4x5-textif-x-ne#comment7302840_3551258) indicates, since using the $f(0) = 3x + 5 = 5$ definition for $x \neq 0$ since $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 - 4x + 5 = 5$, you have that your $2$ definitions are basically the same as the one of $f(x) = x^2 - 4x + 5$ for all real $x$. Thus, $f'(x) = 2x - 4$ is the correct derivative everywhere, including at $x = 0$, instead.